# Java 8 Matcher says there are matches but groupCount is 0

Tags: regex, java-8

Java 8 here. I have the following function:

```
public String extractArgs(String function) {
    Pattern inRegex = Pattern.compile("in\\(.*\\)");
    Matcher inMatch = inRegex.matcher(function);

    log("num in(...) function matches: " + inMatch.groupCount() + "but does inMatch.matches()? " + inMatch.matches());

    if(inMatch.groupCount() > 0) {
        return inMatch.group(1);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

When I pass it `"in(hello)"` as an argument, I get the following output:

```
num in(...) function matches: 0 but does inMatch.matches()? true
```

My *understanding* is that if `inMatch.matches()` returns `true` (which is happening), that I should have at least one match group (`inMatch.groupCount > 0`).

I'm trying to compare the inputted arg string against the regex and (if there is a match) obtain the blurb of text that is contained inside the "`in(...)` function". Hence if I call `extractArgs("in(hello)")` then it should return the string `"hello"`. Where am I going awry?!

Comment: The `groupCount()` method returns the number of capture groups. You don't have capture groups in your pattern. Try for example `Pattern.compile('in\\((.*)\\)');` to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no capture groups in your original regex. To introduce a capture group (which you want), you should define the regular expression along the lines of:

```
 in\\((.*)\\)
```

Note that I've added a `()` brackets around where the arguments supposed to go. This way I have created a capture group around `.*`, so you will now have the groups:

```
pattern.matcher("in(hello, World!)").group(1) // hello, World!
```